# How to dynamic load the document content into an iframe?

Tags: javascript, html, css, iframe

I would like to make something like this

```
|--------------------------|
|                A         |
|        ____________      |
|       |            |     |
|       |            |     |
|       |      B     |     |
|       |            |     |
|       |____________|     |
|                          |
|__________________________|
```

The B page is inside the A page, and I want to insert all the js, css, into the A page, and I want to separate the B page, and I design it to use a iFrame, and get the b page dynamically. But if I use the src in the B page iframe, the A page js, css can't control it... How can I exactly insert all the B page code inside the A page, but don't need copy&paste all the code from B page to A page? Thank you.

Comment: Can you explain the effect you are trying to achieve with the IFrame? Why did you use an IFrame? If we understand the reasons, we may be able to come up with a better option.

Comment: Are you using a server-side programming language? I am sure that you could build a simple script that dynamically loads the contents of your B-pages into your A-page.

Answer (score 3):

You may want to look at an AJAX solution. This way you avoid the iframe and associated complexity. On the A page you can create a div tag with a specific id. Then using AJAX you can load the content of the B page into the div tag.

The HTML that is loaded can then directly be manipulated by the code on your A page since it is essentially one page.

If you are using plain javascript then you will find all the info you need in [this tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/Ajax/default.asp).

If on the other hand you wish to use jQuery then it is as simple as:

```
  $('#myDiv').load('B.html');
```

where myDiv is the ID of your div.

Comment: Why is this upvoted as the answer? The question is about using an IFRAME (which is what I'm looking for) and now I'm hunting through a number of seemingly-related answers that are not related to the question.

Comment: @xxbbcc This answer solves the main problem that the original poster has. The problem is not that they need to use an iframe. Rather it is about including code on the page and then manipulating it. Maybe you can ask a more specific question and see what else comes up.

Answer (score 2):

```
$('#iframeId').contents().find('html').html(yourContent);
```